# Ubuntu installation alternative via USB stick on Lenovo IdeaPad S540

Tags: boot, windows, lenovo

I recently took the brave step of attempting to install Ubuntu onto my Lenovo IdeaPad S540, however until now I have not been successful. It originally has windows 10 installed. I followed the instructions on the site: [Ubuntu installation on computers with Intel(R) RST enabled](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347).But when I have to enter the following code into the command prompt (as specified in one of the last steps):

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
```

Or any of the other alternatives thereof, I simply get a message that the element is not found. I was advised in a previous question to restore my computer back to its original state such that the members of this community could help me install Ubuntu from the beginning. I have restored my computer to its previous state. I simply want to download Ubuntu and delete Windows. The USB stick is ready with the ISO file, so where do I go from here? Obviously the link above was of no help to me.

Comment: Can you get into the menus of the UEFI//BIOS system of your computer? There should be instructions about it in the computer's manual (if you can't find the paper manual, you should find it via the internet). - In a menu it should be possible to switch from RST to AHCI for the drive. Advanced Host Controller Interface (AHCI) is a technical standard defined by Intel that specifies the operation of Serial ATA (SATA) host controllers, and Ubuntu prefers AHCI. Then any instructions should work, for example [this link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview).

Comment: Using the link I mentioned above, I was able to switch from RST to AHCI but then my laptop did not boot and continuously went into a diagnosing cycle.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to boot live (from the USB drive) - and trying to install? Does the computer boot live? If not, have you checked with md5sum or sha256sum that the download was good? What method/tool did you use to create the USB drive? If the computer boots live from the USB drive, please describe what works, and does not work, when you try to install Ubuntu. - Please edit your original question instead of answering with comments.